# .htaccess redirect one of the domain path

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have two domains:

```
1. www.domain1.com
2. www.domain2.com
```

Both domains have an identical path:

```
www.domain1.com/product-name.html
www.domain2.com/product-name.html
```

I want to redirect

**www.domain1.com/product-name.html** to **www.domain1.com/product-number.html**,

but keep **www.domain2.com.product-name.html** not being redirected.

I tried

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain1\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^product-name.html /product-number.html [NC,QSA]
```

No luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: You're not providing enough info. is the real name of the file `product-name.html` or is that an example. Also if this is put in the htaccess of the domain1 docroot it shouldn't affect domain2 anyway.

Comment: @JamesH Better you show your full .htaccess here

Comment: @PanamaJack these two domain are sharing one .htaccess file. product-name.html is an example.